# Transparency channel for point cloud for Open3D

Tags: python, open3d

Is there a way in Open3D (Python) to set the transparency channel for a given point cloud ? I have searched for quite a long time and was not able to find anything. I found a discussion on the project's [Github](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/1927) which hints that this is possible but I could not find any example.

Would anyone have some kind of idea on how to do it?